# Некорректное отображение сайта в Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Загрузила сайт на хостинг, в гугл, яндекс, мозиле и тд все работает нормально, но в Internet Explorer нет. Например, не читается ни один из .script. Задала цвет main, он не отобразился, все белое. Что с этим можно сделать?
Заранее благодарю.
Если что сайт https://pravonazashchitu.ru/

Comment: Добавьте строку: `if(/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) alert("Install a real browser, man");` и все сразу заработает как надо!

Comment: @Leonid а почему еще ошибки в консоли есть? Мб из-за них еще не работает?

Comment: @ArtemL. попробуйте сайт https://jsfiddle.net/ в IE, вот что я имею в виду.

Comment: @Leonid Добавила ваш код (его первую часть), не помогло. А что он должен был сделать?

Comment: Он в случае обнаружения IE должен выдавать системное сообщение. Текст сообщения можете составить сами. Или показать модальное окно, в котором сообщите, что IE не поддерживается сайтом. И дать несколько ссылок на скачивание современных браузеров. Это надо было сделать всем уже 15 лет назад и Microsoft уже давно бы перешел на Chromium/V8 как Яндекс-браузер. А сейчас то чего заморачиваться, сообщите пользователям, что их браузер не поддерживает современный вэб и предложите альтернативы. Так будет лучше для всех.

Comment: @Leonid Хорошо, поняла. Спасибо!